# Why is the "beautiful captive" called "beautiful" if she doesn't have to be?

Tags: marriage, army-military-war, intermarriage

The Torah says:

> When you take ... your enemies ... captive, and you see among them a woman of beautiful form (אֵ֖שֶׁת יְפַת-תֹּאַר), and you desire her, you may take her to yourself as a wife. [Deuteronomy 21:11]

Why does she have to be "beautiful"?

The Midrash says:

> Whence do I derive that the same applies to an ugly woman? From "and you desire her": even if she is not beautiful. If so, why is it written "of beautiful form"? Scripture speaks of the common instance. [Sifrei Devarim 211:7]

This is not really an answer; or rather, not an answer to the real question: What would have been lost if the Torah had just said "a woman" instead of "a woman of beautiful form"?

Or HaHayyim writes:

> The Torah was very careful to write בה, "something within her" instead of אותה, "her." This means that the soldier is not infatuated with the body of the woman but with something inside her, her holy soul which he was able to recognize.

One can be forgiven for being skeptical.

Any other reasons why the word "beautiful" had to be there?

Comment: With the noteworthy exception of Spartans (who did not write much to begin with), the ancients were not particularly parsimonious with words. The idea is that the only explanation for the desire would have been physical attraction; though arranged marriages were not uncommon (and traditional communities around the world still preserve them: Judaism, Islam, Hinduism, etc.), it is clear that no sane parent would contract such a highly undesirable arrangement for their offspring.

Answer (score 3):

So the [Ibn Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.21.11?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Deuteronomy.21.11.2&lang2=bi) writes similarly to the Ohr HaChaim that you bring:

> **יפת תאר**. בעיניו
>
> ***Beautiful** in his eyes.*

This idea is noted by Rambam in [Mishneh Torah, Melachim UMilchamos 8:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.8.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) who adds explicitly even if she is not pretty.

An alternative approach however, is taken in the Vilna Gaon in [Aderes Eliyahu](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.21.11?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Aderet_Eliyahu%2C_Deuteronomy.21.11.3&lang2=bi) where he notes that the term 'beautiful' is more to demonstrate the effect of the Yetzer Hara:

> יפת תאר. לא דברה תורה אלא כנגד יצה״ר. אע״פ שהיא כעורה שנאמר וחשקת (כי חשק הוא דבוק בלי שום טעם):
>
> *Beautiful. The Torah only states (the term "beautiful") opposite the Yetzer Hara (the evil inclination). Even if she is ugly it says "וחשקת" - "And you desire her" (because he desired to come close (lit. cling) without any other reason).*

The Maharal in [Gur Aryeh](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.21.11?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Gur_Aryeh_on_Devarim.21.11.1&lang2=bi) asks this exact question and develops this idea of the Yetzer Hara. He writes that when seeing such a woman the Yetzer Hara is "להתגרות באדם" - i.e. it awakens a real desire for this lady.

Alternatively, the [Rosh on the Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.21.11?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rosh_on_Torah%2C_Deuteronomy.21.11.1&lang2=bi) asks this question and answers:

> וי"ל מפני שהם במצור ומפני הרעב שבעיר משתנות פניהם לכך אמר יפת תאר כלומר שהיא ראויה לקבל היופי שחסרה בימי הרעב
>
> *And there are those who say that because of siege and because of famine that is in the city, lit. their faces changed (I am assuming this means that the sense of worry and stress of the situation made them look more haggard etc.) therefore, it says "beautiful woman" which means that she was fitting to receive this beauty which would have been lacking in the days of famine.*

Answer (score 3):

There is a general rule that the Torah describes things in the usual case even when it the application is broader (דברה תורה בהוה). See [this list](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%94%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) and [this one](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%94%D7%95%D7%94&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance).